# Laravel Eloquent - How do I select columns of the updated row?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to update a single row,
using this query,

```
$update_row = PayRecord::where('date_from',$date_from)
      ->where->('date_to',$date_to)
      ->update(['status',1]);
```

what I want to do is to get the `id` of the updated row, without creating another query to get the id,

```
$get_updated_row_id = PayRecord::where('date_from',$date_from)
          ->where->('date_to',$date_to)'
          ->get('id');
```

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra `->` from where clause.

This may useful to you.

```
$update_row = PayRecord::where('date_from',$date_from)
      ->where('date_to',$date_to)
      ->first();

$update_row->update(['status',1]);

$update_row->id; // to get the id
```